# How do I extract values from a Coffeescript associative array (ie hash) into a simple array?

Tags: arrays, coffeescript, list-comprehension, associative-array

I have a simple associative array in `Coffeescript` as follows

```
things = 
  login: 'login/'
  search: 'search/'
  custard: 'trampoline/'
```

and I want to generate an array `['login/', 'search/', 'trampoline/']`

Sure I could do this:

```
  thArr = []
  for k, v of things
    thArr.push v
```

but I'm sure there is a one-line way to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  thArr = (v for k, v of things)
```

Comment: yay - thanks.  I tried `thArr = v for k,v of things` but that didn't work. the parentheses made the difference.  You rock!

Comment: It would be nice to mention _why_ the parentheses make that work. It's because the expression between parenthesis is an _array_ comprehension. What you posted was a _clause_ comprehension, `thArr = v` is executed for every `k, v` pair.

Answer (score -2):

If you know what index the key => value are located at.
e.g

```
arr = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

Object.values(arr)[0]
```

result:
= 1
*because a: 1 is at index 0